# How to repeat an image on the right and left with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply CSS transformations to an image to achieve the following result:

```
right half of the image - main image - left half of the image
```

so that after CSS is applied to the image it looks like a "ribbon" with the image repeating after and before but not fully.

Is there a way to do this without changing the structure of the page (that is without using a div and background property)?

Example:

[image to apply CSS to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89dOA.png)

[result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGzrT.png)

I tried using background and it kinda works

```
background-image: url(/image.png);
background-repeat-x: repeat;
background-size: 50%;
background-position-x: 50%;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
height: 50px;
```

but I would like to get the same effect without using background rules but rules that apply to the image directly.

I tried also to apply the background rules to the img directly and got this result which could be a good middle-ground solution except for the missing image icon overlapping. The removal of this icon could also do the trick.

[result by using background on img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPa4p.png)

Unfortunately, I cannot change the structure of the page (e.g. by wrapping the image into a div)

Comment: can you explain briefly by adding some code or example with image

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show certain parts of an image it's good practice to go with the `background-position` property in combination with `background-size`.

Other method is to cut the images to fit your needs and then display them seperatly.

*I suggest you to go with my example:*

```css
.image {
  height: 400px;
}

.image>div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 150px;
}

.left {
  background: url("https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2018/05/17/you-can-train-your-cat/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg") no-repeat right;
  background-size: cover;
}

.middle {
  background: url("https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2018/05/17/you-can-train-your-cat/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
}

.right {
  background: url("https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2018/05/17/you-can-train-your-cat/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg") no-repeat left;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you like cats. I do.